# Check if two views overlap in react native

Tags: react-native

Does anyone have any idea how one would go about to check if two views (child views of a parent container) overlap in react native?

It would also be nice if i didn't be a super stressful operation (i.e. measuring all views and alike) since I would like it to be done quite frequently.

Any ideas are much appreciated! :)

Edit:
I realize that my question was really generic, so I'll try to make it a bit more clear cut.

What I want to achieve is some kind of watcher function to detect a collision between two views that can change position on re render.

E.g.(Sorry I can't embed images due to too low rep):
[Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbzTq.png)

In the image above the two views can change position on a specific event, And I need a callback for when these two overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Its a very generic question... Yet I do have some tips From my experience with react-native. Usually when you can't see a component in the view its because of the following reasons:

- If you have UI components such as View, Image in 'absolute' position, Make sure you cancel that property and check if its render.
- If its a large component, that for some reason cannot be render, replace it with a smaller simpler component to see if its renders so you could make sure the problem is in the view and not in the pure code. I usually just put a Text component with some jibrish inside just to test errors just like that.
- If the component is a flexbox/inside one - Sometimes adding a combination of the following helps:

  `flex: 1
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems, 'center',
  flexDirection: 'row'`
- I cannot explain it, but I had a number of occurrences where i deleted the `flex: 1` property and it helped, make sure you check that.
- Make sure you actually returning an item in complex inner loops. for example:

WRONG:

`myList.map( (item) => { return <View>{item}</View> } )`

CORRECT:

`return myList.map( (item) => { return <View>{item}</View> } )`

- Also make sure you enable hot reload & remote debugging(shake device) - extremely helpful and makes you code 5x times faster

Comment: Thank you for your response, but my question wasn't really about styling. Please see my edit for a better explanation of the problem.